# Jquery addEventListener and mouseover triggered only once

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
var $els = document.querySelectorAll('#site-nav a');
for(i = 0; i < $els.length; i++) {

        $els[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            console.log('yessss');
        });

}
```

when hovering the element with the mouse I can see the message in the console, but the first time only. Am I doing anything wrong?

thanks

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: The code shown is correct. If I create some random <a> tags inside a wrapper with id #site-nav, I get a log every hover. Can't reproduce problem.

Comment: Removing `jquery` tag because this code doesn't use jquery.

Comment: Make sure you console does not group the same messages into one. For example add some random stuff `console.log(new Date())`

Comment: ok probably I am messing with the html that is really bad, sorry. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This code seems to work as written: try running the code below. 
If you offer a little bit more context we might be able to help more effectively. That being said, it may be worth noting that the mouseover event fires when the mouse enters the element, and doesn't fire constantly while it's over the element.

```js
var $els = document.querySelectorAll('#site-nav a');
for(i = 0; i < $els.length; i++) {

        $els[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            console.log('yessss');
        });

}
```

```html
<div id="site-nav"><a>Some link</a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you are looking for by using the .each() function to traverse through all the a elements with id site-nav. I believe it puts all elements into an array for you.

$('#site-nav a').each(function({
\code goes here,you  can use $(this) to reference the current a element.
}));

Also watch out when using an id as a selector. Id's are meant for one time use and are meant to be specific to one dom element. Don't know the explanation but iv'e tried to achieve what you are doing using ID's and it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

The code you have works as expected:

If you look at the image you'll see only one line but a number in front of it, that number will increase each time you hover over the link:

```
var $els = document.querySelectorAll('#site-nav a');
for(i = 0; i < $els.length; i++) {

        $els[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            console.log('yessss');
        });

}
```

[image]

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kkwc3mLn/

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery that could be simply :

```
$('body').on('mouseover', '#site-nav a', function(){
    console.log('yessss');
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('body').on('mouseover', '#site-nav a', function(){
    console.log('yessss');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="site-nav">
  <a href="#">Link1</a>
  <a href="#">Link2</a>
  <a href="#">Link3</a>
</div>
```